# Changing colour on buttons in tableview cell edit actions

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uitableviewrowaction

**Hello!**

Having a go at swipe-to-delete functions and the likes in tableView cells today...

**When toggling a button I would like it to change colours from green to red and back again.** - Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

For the toggle button I have declared a boolean which is set
to false at start.

and this is what I've got inside editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:

```
  ...

let toggleAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Toggle", handler: {     (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

let button: UIButton = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

if(self.toggleBool == false) {

    self.toggleBool = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

} else {                
    self.toggleBool = false 
    toggleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}

self.view.addSubview(button)


})



return [deleteAction, toggleAction]
}
```

*The code snippet above does not make the button change colour when pressed!*

Any help in the matter would be much appreciated!